# weird login screen in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, login-screen

Normally when I boot the computer up, I am presented with the login screen where I am asked to enter a 4 digit pin in order to login to windows.

but today when I boot up those things happend:

1. Normally the screen that I will first see is this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgGE9.jpg)

   but now what I saw was a blue background like this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5jq2.png)
2. Sometimes when I boot up the computer its automatically telling me that I had too many wrong attempts and I need to write the password A1B2C3 to continue (and I didn't even did enything)
3. Insted of getting the screen that asked me to enter the PIN I got a blank screen (not sure about the color) and a cmd window that looked something like this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YLZk.png)

I enterd my PIN because I was very confused but now I think it was a mistake...

And after this everything was normal

Is this normal or a virus?

(sorry for my bad English)

Comment: I think somehow you got a temporary user profile and then somehow again, entering your PIN was able to get to your normal profile. If you can restart, use your PIN and the computer starts OK, you should be fine.  You can always do a full scan with Windows Defender.

Comment: Ok thank you very much !

Comment: If I post my comment as an Answer - will you find that helpful?

Comment: Yes I think it will.